# Why is Jenkins picking up a Git change but not deploying the built Docker image properly?

Tags: git, docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am using Jenkins to build a Docker image from Git. It picks up commits and build but the changes are not copied to the Docker image or container.

The Jenkins log gives the following:

```
Obtained Jenkinsfile from git ssh://git@git-server/~/srv/git/ci-cd.git
Running in Durability level: MAX_SURVIVABILITY
[Pipeline] Start of Pipeline
[Pipeline] node
Running on Jenkins in /var/jenkins_home/workspace/Hello-Kenzan
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] checkout
using credential f3eca4e6-91ce-400e-bfb9-50595e15c629
 > git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
 > git config remote.origin.url ssh://git@git-server/~/srv/git/ci-cd.git # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from ssh://git@git-server82.217.168.15/~/srv/git/ci-cd.git
 > git --version # timeout=10
using GIT_ASKPASS to set credentials 
 > git fetch --tags --progress ssh://git@git-server/~/srv/git/ci-cd.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
 > git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/master^{commit} # timeout=10
 > git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/origin/master^{commit} # timeout=10
Checking out Revision ee1b2052f28953e92707ee7beb8b4a517482327a (refs/remotes/origin/master)
 > git config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
 > git checkout -f ee1b2052f28953e92707ee7beb8b4a517482327a
Commit message: "nl"
 > git rev-list --no-walk 7816c951c76ea7e3b82377141a3311897d54fecb # timeout=10
[Pipeline] sh
+ git rev-parse --short HEAD
[Pipeline] readFile
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Build)
[Pipeline] sh
+ docker build -t 127.0.0.1:30400/hello-kenzan:ee1b205 -f applications/hello-kenzan/Dockerfile applications/hello-kenzan
Sending build context to Docker daemon  71.68kB

Step 1/4 : FROM nginx:latest
 ---> e445ab08b2be
Step 2/4 : COPY index.html /usr/share/nginx/html/index.html
 ---> e8491c90fec9
Step 3/4 : COPY DockerFileEx.jpg /usr/share/nginx/html/DockerFileEx.jpg
 ---> 23c103d92be1
Step 4/4 : EXPOSE 80
 ---> Running in 6fe353a8413f
Removing intermediate container 6fe353a8413f
 ---> eb10aa423060
Successfully built eb10aa423060
Successfully tagged 127.0.0.1:30400/hello-kenzan:ee1b205
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Push)
[Pipeline] sh
+ docker push 127.0.0.1:30400/hello-kenzan:ee1b205
The push refers to repository [127.0.0.1:30400/hello-kenzan]
6b054581244f: Preparing
46e19e093201: Preparing
fe6a7a3b3f27: Preparing
d0673244f7d4: Preparing
d8a33133e477: Preparing
d0673244f7d4: Layer already exists
fe6a7a3b3f27: Layer already exists
d8a33133e477: Layer already exists
6b054581244f: Pushed
46e19e093201: Pushed
ee1b205: digest: sha256:c227f17d4b5521a09e66474ae09fb81227af6613e0c77fcfb4f5c714b03ff39a size: 1364
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Deploy)
[Pipeline] kubernetesDeploy
Starting Kubernetes deployment
```

So it gives `> git checkout -f ee1b2052f28953e92707ee7beb8b4a517482327a
Commit message: "nl"` which is the most recent change.
Then it gives

```
> git rev-list --no-walk 7816c951c76ea7e3b82377141a3311897d54fecb # timeout=10
[Pipeline] sh
+ git rev-parse --short HEAD
[Pipeline] readFile
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Build)
[Pipeline] sh
+ docker build -t 127.0.0.1:30400/hello-kenzan:ee1b205 -f applications/hello-kenzan/Dockerfile applications/hello-kenzan
Sending build context to Docker daemon  71.68kB

Step 1/4 : FROM nginx:latest
 ---> e445ab08b2be
Step 2/4 : COPY index.html /usr/share/nginx/html/index.html
 ---> e8491c90fec9
```

so it seems to copy the index.html file (that I changed). Although I'm not sure about the identifiers. Then at the end, it deplys containers, but I don't see these specific identfiers in the `docker ps` output.
When I log in to the Jenkins container and look in the workspace, it contains the changed file. When I log in to the container running the code, /usr/share/nginx/html/index.html is the old file.

I expect the changed index.html to be there.

Comment: `root@jenkins-5d65969dcf-5brcp:/var/jenkins_home/workspace# ls
Hello-Kenzan  Hello-Kenzan@tmp` I see two folders here but the @tmp is empty

Comment: `curl http://10.103.244.162:5000/v2/hello-kenzan/tags/list` gives: 
`{"name":"hello-kenzan","tags":["7816c95","latest","3187295","ee1b205"]}`

Answer (score 0):

The tags led me to further look into the log and it showed two deployments being built by Jenkins. The latter overwriting the former and using the `:latest` tag. Using that tag is also bad practice, but I had missed this before.